# Set Arbitrary Amount Of Scissors Each Frame Between Draw Commands

Tags: c++, vulkan

I need to know if it is possible to change the scissor rect between multiple draw commands.

```
VkCmdSetScissor
VkCmdDraw..
VkCmdDraw..
VkCmdSetScissor
VkCmdDraw..
VkCmdDraw..
VkCmdSetScissor
VkCmdDraw..
VkCmdDraw..
VkCmdSetScissor
```

In the above psudocode I would set the scissor rect to different coordinates on the screen between each set of drawing commands. The scissors would be different sizes each time.

Currently, it seems as though only the last call to `VkCmdSetScissor` is the one that ends up being applied.

My application needs to set dozens of different small scissors on the screen to draw GUI elements. There is currently no way to know how many scissors will be needed each frame nor is there any conceivable way of knowing how many scissors would be needed during pipeline creation.

Comment: Have you set `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR` for your pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, and the psudocode above is exactly how it should be done. Of course you do have to set `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR` on your pipeline.

My issue was that I was using a single `VkCmdDraw` command to draw the entire GUI. After splitting up the individual GUI elements into `VkCmdDrawIndirectCommand` and placing a `VkCmdSetScissor` between each appropriate `VkCmdDrawIndirect` everything started to work properly.